# how to get only saved bookmark page from crome browser and display in android app?

Tags: android

```
  final String[] columns = { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
    Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,columns, null, null, null);
    query.moveToFirst();
    while (query.moveToNext()) {
    String title = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
    String url = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
    Log.d("msg"," d  "+title+"  d "+url);
    urlArray.add(url);
    }

final String[] columns = { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,columns, null, null, null);
query.moveToFirst();
while (query.moveToNext()) {
String title = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
String url = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
Log.d("msg"," d  "+title+"  d "+url);
urlArray.add(url);
}
```

I have use this code but this code give me browser history i want to get only bookmark page url.

Comment: This code [will not work on Android 6.0+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser).

Comment: yes but even earlier version its not giving me proper result